# TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int' comparing user input to an integer

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I am trying to make a game. I am making a zodiac code and each time I run it, I get TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'.

I know that I am missing an int(input(___)), but I am not sure where to put it.

Here is my code:

```
if month in monthList:

 if month == "January": 
  sign = "Capricorn" if (day < 20) else "Aquarius"
  signDescription = description1

 elif month == "February":  
  sign = "Aquarius" if (day < 19) else "Pisces"
  signDescription = description2

 elif month == "March":
  sign = "Pisces" if (day < 21) else "Aries"
  signDescription = description3
```

Comment: Please always include the complete Traceback. Format it as code.

Comment: You need to add more to your example. We need to be able to copy and paste from your question and run it. As is there is too much missing from your example. Please read [mre].

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't see `<=` in this code - so your error  can be in different part. Error should show you in which part of code you have problem - so first you could use `print()`, `print(type(...))` to see what you have in variables in this line. It seem you forgot `int()` to convert string to number.

Answer (score -1):

From what I can see, the problem is you are trying to compare a number and a word. This can easily be fixed by making one of the variables match the other. For example,`A = "1"` and `B = 2` A is a string and B is an integer.
If you try to compare these two each other e.g

```
if A <= B:
    print("yes")
```

Then that will not work and it will return the error you are having a problem with.
However, if you turn A into an integer with

```
A = int(A)
```

Then it will work. Another option is you could turn B into a string, with

```
B = str(B)
```

Hopefully, this answers the question

Comment: Equality will work, it will just always return False

Comment: Very true, sorry about that I meant something like: if A<=B: print('yes')